# How to tell if a kernel module is called while boot

Tags: linux-kernel

For instance:

```
static int __init hugetlb_init(){
    ......
}
module_init(hugetlb_init);
```

And there is no `#ifdef CONFIG_xxx` before it.
Does it mean that it is a manual insert module which won't be inserted during boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But there is a CONFIG_HUGETLBFS in mm/Makefile

```
obj-$(CONFIG_HUGETLBFS) += hugetlb.o
```

given the fact that CONFIG_HUGETLBFS is boolean,

```
config HUGETLBFS
        bool "HugeTLB file system support"
```

you can either make it built-in (=y) or kick it out of kernel (=n). So, hugetlbfs can't be a module that you can manually insert into kernel.